# Navigation action/destination action cannot be found from the current destination in FragmentResultListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

Navigation doesn't work if I call `findNavController()` inside `FragmentResultListener`, though if I add some delay than it works

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination
> action cannot be found from the current destination

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    ...

    setFragmentResultListener(MyFragment.RESULT_SOME_EVENT) { _, b ->
       
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
            delay(1000L) // if I remove it then I receive the crash
            findNavController().navigate(
                MyFragmentDirections.actionGoToAnotherFragment()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

I show some fragment dialog with two buttons, after user selects something it set result for fragment, dialog dismiss and after that on parent fragment it should change destination - go to next fragment

I understand why it happens, navigation component thinks that fragment dialog is still showing but I use `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed` and still it doesn't help, only until I add some delay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fixed by changing logic inside fragment dialog from:

```
binding.someButton.setOnClickListener {
    setFragmentResult(....)
    dismiss()
}
```

to:

```
binding.someButton.setOnClickListener {
    findNavController().navigateUp() // sync method 
    setFragmentResult(....)
}
```